# Kinect camera with visp auto tracker

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use the package  "Visp_auto_tracker for detecting QR codes. I plan to use the tracklive_firewire.launch for doing the job. But this launch file uses the firewire camera. Being very new to ROS, i don't know how to replace this with the kinect parameters. I'm very new to ROS so I would be very grateful for expert help.

I already downloaded the kinect 2 drivers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254278/kinect-camera-with-visp-auto-tracker/) by [sid_25](https://answers.ros.org/users/29315/sid_25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I don't know exactly for ROS, but for the native ViSP library it already includes a class for freenect (kinect v1) you can check it [here](https://visp.inria.fr/3rd_freenect/) so I have used it to create some applications, for example to track some blobs. Check this [repository](https://github.com/ghanimmukhtar/customized_blob_tracker.git) you can write you own ros node in the same manner, use (tutorial-kinect-sensor.cpp and tutorial-barcode-detector.cpp) to produce what you want then you can write your own launch file or just run it directly.

Hopes this helps,
Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) with karma: 41 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0